# Nifi Template Export: Variables are not getting exported

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to export Nifi template and import it in another Nifi instance. However, we observed that variables which are defined as PG scope are not there when i import the template in another Nifi instance.

It seems Nifi template don't export variables.  So, what is the way to export variables also when we export Nifi template.

Did i miss anything obvious  ?

Regards

Comment: what do you mean by `variables which are defined as PG scope` ?

Comment: In the Process Group, I can define variables by right clicking on the canvas. These variables will be available for the all the processors in PG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to create a template that *includes* the process group where the variables are defined. Let's say you define a variable `variable1` inside process group `PG 1` and then reference it in a processor `processor 1`.

If you select `processor 1` and right-click to "Create template", the variable definition will not be exported in the template. However, if you go "up" one level and select `PG 1`, then right-click and "Create template", the variable will be defined in the template in a block such as:

```
    <processGroups>
        ...
        <name>PG 1</name>
        <variables>
            <entry>
                <key>variable1</key>
                <value>This is a variable value. </value>
            </entry>
        </variables>
        ...
    </processGroups>
```

You may also be interested in how variables work with [NiFi Registry](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-registry-docs/index.html) (flow versioning is the preferred solution for flow snippet reusability, as templates will likely eventually be deprecated). In addition, the [new feature work around *parameters*](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Better+Support+for+Parameterizing+Flows) will allow for a cleaner interface, protection of sensitive values, and more.